# ajax post with laravel 5.6

Tags: ajax, laravel

I can't figure out how to get this ajax request to post.

```
     <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="ajaxSubmit">Submit</button>

      <textarea rows="4" class="form-control resize_vertical" id="application_notes" name="application_notes" placeholder="Notes">{{$application->notes}}</textarea>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var url = "/instructor-notes-save/{{$application->id}}"
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
              });
            $.ajax({

                  url: url,
                  method: 'post',
                  data: {
                     application_notes: jQuery('#application_notes').val(),
                  },
                  success: function(response){
                     console.log(response);
                  }});
               });
            });
</script>
```

My controller is this:

```
public function saveNotes(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $application = Application::findOrFail($id);
      $application->notes = $request->application_notes;
      $application->save();
      return response()->json(['success'=>'Data is successfully added']);
    }
```

And for what it's worth, here is my route:

```
Route::post('/instructor-notes-save/{id}', 'InstructorsController@saveNotes')->name('instructor.save.note');
```

What am i missing to get this ajax request to work? In my console log, i get a 419 unknown status error.

Comment: Are you sure the meta tag is visible and meta name is `_token` not `csrf-token`?

Comment: i just tried changing it per your suggestion and it still didn't work. I copied most of this code from a tutorial online. Of course i tried to change it for my purposes but i'm stuck. but no, the "csrf-token" did not produce success

Comment: Ok, check your layout view, if `<meta name="_token" />` is present.

Comment: it is not. where do i add that?

Comment: Depends on what layout file are you using. Do you use `views/master.blade.php` i guess or `views/layouts/app.blade.php`?

Comment: i'm using a template.   <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'> that's in the header of the template

Comment: Add this code in your template / layout file. `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: that also produced a 419 error in the console log. This is a premium theme that i paid for. I haven't touched any of their native js files that came with it. It's my first experience with themes and such and i'm not exactly an ajax/js whiz. any other tricks? or would you like the github repo?

Comment: Remember to change the name of the meta tag to `_token` depending on that you define in your ajaxSetup. Yes you can share me the github repo

Comment: [https://github.com/maximus1127/drive] the files in question are layouts.auditorDefault, auditor_pages.application_review, and ApplicationsController

Comment: changing the name as you suggested did not produce an error anymore but it did not produce success either. the console log basically logged the html format of the layout file

Comment: Of course it will produce html format, because in your controller in `saveNotes` function you are returning `return redirect(route('auditor'));`, you must return array to return it as json, example, `return ['success' => true]`

Comment: `return response()->json(['success'=>'Data is successfully added']);` i'm not sure why it says that. this is what i currently have in my saveNotes method right now on my computer

Comment: I'm looking at `InstructorsController.php` in your github. it says `return redirect(route('auditor'));`

Comment: that's why. go to ApplicationsController

Comment: freak.....are you telling me this entire stinking time that i've been posting to the wrong stupid route???? omg..........

Comment: That's what i'm telling you.

Comment: bruh......it works now. i can't believe i was posting to the wrong route this entire time. thanks for your time with me aceraven :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check that the meta tag `_token` is present in your layout file inside the `<head>` tag.

Also please make sure that the AJAX url is present in your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

add the following tag in your html `<head>`:

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`