# How to pass Holiday Dates from controller in View in Laravel using JSON

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using JQuery-UI datepicker in Laravel-5.8

Controller:

```
public function findNationalHoliday(Request $request)
{
    $nationalholidays               = HrHolidayDate::select('holiday_date')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))->get();
    return response()->json([
        'nationalholidays' => $nationalholidays,
    ]);        
}
```

View

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('change', '#leave_type', function() {
                var air_id =  $(this).val();
                var a = $(this).parent();
                var op = "";
                
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '{{ route('get.enationalholidays.all') }}',
                    data: { 'id': air_id },
                    dataType: 'json',      //return data will be json
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#nationalholidays').val(data.nationalholidays);
                    },
                    error:function(){

                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#leave_days").on('keyup blur', function (e) {
                var periodval=parseInt($("#leave_days").val());

                var startDate = $('.start_date');
                var endDate = $('.end_date');

                var dte = startDate.datepicker("getDate"); 
                        dte.setDate(dte.getDate()+periodval); 
                        endDate.datepicker("setDate", dte);            

              });

                $( '.start_date' ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,      
                    showAnim: 'slideDown',
                    duration: 'fast',   
                    minDate: +1,
                    setDate: new Date(),
                    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                    yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
            }).datepicker('setDate', '1');

                $( '.end_date' ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,      
                    showAnim: 'slideDown',
                    duration: 'fast',   
                    minDate: +1,
                    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                    yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
                    enableOnReadonly: true,
                    beforeShow: function(i) { if ($(i).attr('readonly')) { return false; } }
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Initially, I got this error:

http://localhost:8888/myproject/get/findNationalHoliday?id=2 500 (Internal Server Error)

> carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php(645): Carbon\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-08-24 00:0...', NULL)
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\Models\Hr\HrHolidayDate.php(109): Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-08-24 00:0...')

but when I removed the accessors in the HrHolidate model:

```
public function setHolidayDateAttribute($input)
{
    $this->attributes['holiday_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $input);
}   

public function getHolidayDateAttribute($input)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $input)->format(config('app.date_format'));   
}
```

I got this result

[image: jquery console]

How do I utilize the result

In the code, I have leave_days, start_date and end_date. end_date is disabled. While leave_days on keyup, I add leave_days to start_date to get end_date.

But I also have a model called HrHolidayDate which has a field, holiday_date in date format. I use json in controller to send it to view.

How do I consume the holiday_date in the view and remove it from my result in end_date calculation?

Thanks

Comment: use Ajax then response will  come in success

Comment: @LalitKumar - How do I achieve that. Can you show me a sample from my code? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477778/ajax-post-with-laravel-5-6 , you can follow this for ajax or you can google , there are various sample  code of Ajax

Comment: @LalitKumar - Already I used ajax via #leave_type on change. How do I incorporate it into #leave_days

Comment: there is syntax error in your controller

Comment: https://phppot.com/demo/php-calendar-event-management-using-fullcalendar-javascript-library/ 

check this , it may help you

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov - I have updated the code